# Google maps does not show route properly if Google maps is not running already

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I am implementing functionality in my application where user can see a route from his current location to destination location. When user taps on a button I open Google Maps app like this

```
if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(NSURL(string:"comgooglemaps://")!) {

            let urlStr = String(format: "comgooglemaps://?saddr=&daddr=%f,%f&directionsmode=driving&zoom=14", lat, lng)
            let url = NSURL(string:urlStr)!
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)

}
```

By leaving `saddr` param empty so Google maps may pick my current location. But Google maps does not show route first time if Google maps is not running already. It only shows my current location and a loading circle appears. But it works fine if Google maps is running and I open maps to show route.

Has anyone faced the same issue? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem with iOS 14, do you have any update?

Answer (score 0):

let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(0, longitude:-165, zoom:2)
let mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera:camera)

```
let path = GMSMutablePath()
path.addLatitude(-33.866, longitude:151.195) 
path.addLatitude(-18.142, longitude:178.431) 
path.addLatitude(21.291, longitude:-157.821)
path.addLatitude(37.423, longitude:-122.091) 

let polyline = GMSPolyline(path: path)
polyline.strokeColor = UIColor.blueColor()
polyline.strokeWidth = 5.0
polyline.map = mapView

self.view = mapView
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the answer @raheem. But this code draws map within the application but I am talking about opening Google Maps as separate application.

Comment: UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
 
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"comgooglemaps://?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f", self.startLocation.latitude, self.startLocation.longitude, self.destinationLocation.latitude, self.destinationLocation.longitude] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    
 [app openURL:url];

Comment: try to pass separate latitude longitude for source and destination .